# Apache Directory Studio get error with openJDK 17

Tags: java-17, apache-directory

Error: The JVM shared library "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/server/libjvm.dylib"
does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.

Apache Directory Studio java[image]

I have tried to install via " brew install apache-directory-studio". Same issue.
Java:     17.0.9 (arm64) "Eclipse Adoptium" - "OpenJDK 17.0.9" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error if I try to launch Apache Directory Studio from Mac's "spotlight search", but it works if I launch it from a terminal with "open /Applications/ApacheDirectoryStudio.app".